# printing stack in the incorrect order in c++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, stack

I have a function that pushes down all non zero integers to the top of my array and then reprints it in a 3x3 matrix.
the problem i am having is when i push all the non zero integers into my stack it reverses the order.

** the indexing of my array is backwards. ie, in a 3x3 matrix the coordinates (0,0) would be the bottom left **

here is the relevant code:

```
  void State::pushDown() {


  std::stack<int> tempStack;

    for ( int c = 0; c < BOARDSIZE; c++ )
    {
        for ( int r = 0; r < BOARDSIZE ; r++ )
        {
            if ( grid[r][c] != 0 ) tempStack.push( grid[r][c] );
        }

        for ( int r = BOARDSIZE; r != 0; --r )
        {
            if ( !tempStack.empty() )
            {
                grid[r-1][c] = tempStack.top();
                tempStack.pop();
            }
            else
            {
                grid[r-1][c] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

}
State() {
        for (int i = 0; i < BOARDSIZE; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < BOARDSIZE; j++)
                grid[i][j] = rand() % 7;

    }

void State::printBoard() {
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < BOARDSIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < BOARDSIZE; j++) {
            cout << " " << grid[BOARDSIZE - i - 1][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    srand(time(0));

    State state;
    state.printBoard();

    state.pushDown();
    state.printBoard();



    return 0;
}
```

here is my current output:

before push down function

```
045
504
226
```

after push down function:

```
006
224
545
```

as you can see it successfully pushes the non zero elements to the bottom of the matrix however in the process it reverses the order of the other numbers and i believe this is because of the stack.

my expected output would be the following:

before push down function

```
045
504
226
```

after push down function:

```
005
544
226
```

My question is- how can i fix my function so that the order of the elements remain the same without reversing.

Comment: Have you tried just using a queue?

Comment: sorry forgot to add i am following university task which would like to use a stack. i tried it will a queue which i worked because i could use the front() property however i can not use queue in this case

Comment: @elie1 -- *i tried it will a queue which i worked* -- Then create a queue using two stacks.  Make it a class, put a `front` member function, and you're done.  The code to make a queue from two stacks is trivial.

Comment: Also, maybe what I suggested is the goal of the assignment given to you.  In other words, in a sneaky, roundabout way, you were supposed to make the queue using stack(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the loops can be defined.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

const int BOARDSIZE = 3;

void reformat( int ( &a )[BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE] )
{
    std::stack<int> tempStack;

    for ( int c = 0; c < BOARDSIZE; c++ )
    {
        for ( int r = 0; r < BOARDSIZE ; r++ )
        {
            if ( a[r][c] != 0 ) tempStack.push( a[r][c] );
        }

        for ( int r = BOARDSIZE; r != 0; --r )
        {
            if ( !tempStack.empty() )
            {
                a[r-1][c] = tempStack.top();
                tempStack.pop();
            }
            else
            {
                a[r-1][c] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int a[BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE] =
    {
        { 0, 4, 5 },
        { 5, 0, 4 },
        { 2, 2, 6 }
    };


    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( const auto &item : row ) std::cout << item << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    reformat( a );

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( const auto &item : row ) std::cout << item << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 4 5 
5 0 4 
2 2 6 

0 0 5 
5 4 4 
2 2 6
```

If you are outputting the array starting from its last row then use the following loops

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

const int BOARDSIZE = 3;

void reformat( int ( &a )[BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE] )
{
    std::stack<int> tempStack;

    for ( int c = 0; c < BOARDSIZE; c++ )
    {
        for ( int r = 0; r < BOARDSIZE ; r++ )
        {
            if ( a[BOARDSIZE-r-1][c] != 0 ) tempStack.push( a[BOARDSIZE-r-1][c] );
        }

        for ( int r = 0; r != BOARDSIZE; ++r )
        {
            if ( !tempStack.empty() )
            {
                a[r][c] = tempStack.top();
                tempStack.pop();
            }
            else
            {
                a[r][c] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int a[BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE] =
    {
        { 2, 2, 6 },
        { 5, 0, 4 },
        { 0, 4, 5 }
    };


    for ( size_t i = 0; i < BOARDSIZE; i++  )
    {
        for ( const auto &item : a[BOARDSIZE - i - 1] ) std::cout << item << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    reformat( a );

     for ( size_t i = 0; i < BOARDSIZE; i++  )
    {
        for ( const auto &item : a[BOARDSIZE - i - 1] ) std::cout << item << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above

```
0 4 5 
5 0 4 
2 2 6 

0 0 5 
5 4 4 
2 2 6
```

But now the array is outputted starting from its last line.

Comment: i am only using my stack to refill my array, and then i print my array as normal. but i used the key components of your code however the output i get pushes the zero to the bottom not the top- remember that in your output before the reformat the value of coordinate 0,0 is 2 and not 0

Comment: @elie1 I have not understood. Is the output of my demonstrative program incorrect?

Comment: your output of your program is incorrect.  while the ordering is correct, the zeros are being displayed in the last row of the matrix and not the top

Comment: @elie1 You are wrong. The demonstrative program outputs the result matrix as is.

Comment: I copied the code exactly and the zeros are on the bottom not top

Comment: Like i mentioned in my question. The indexing on my array is reversed. So grid[0][0] in your sample  output should be 2 and not 0

Comment: @elie1 I have initially this array 0 4 5 
5 0 4 
2 2 6 

that then was converted to this array

0 0 5 
5 4 4 
2 2 6

What is the wrong with the result array?

Comment: i have updated my question to show more of my code that covers me initialising my grid and my print function, hope this can make more sense

Comment: @elie1 What was changed?!  You have an original array and its content you showed you have a result array and its content is showed. What is the difference with arrays from my demonstrative program?!

Comment: i had modified your code slightly, i will update my post now so show my new implementation of the code. i will also mark your answer as question

Comment: please look over my code i have updated it. i copied your code to move the elements around and then instead of using your loops i just called my print function to show me the changes. i think there maybe in error in my print function above as your printing method works however i am unable to change it

Comment: @elie1 You are outputting the array starting from the ,last row cout << " " << grid[BOARDSIZE - i - 1][j] << " "; I am outputting the array starting from the first row.

Comment: Yeah i thought so because i wanted it to start from the last row. Is there a way i can use your code to work with my current output?

Comment: Thankuou for the correct answer. Would you know what was the error in my code. It seems like i had the same code but you used c++11 for the loops where i used for loops